# SQL - Database normalisation

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-normalization

I have the proposed table structure to extend a database:

[image: Proposed table structure]

Within the `OrganisationalAssets` table. The following columns are nullable:

- Organisation_Id
- Location_Id
- Language_Id

The problem we've come across is that the `Organisation_Id` column is only nullable  for certain types of Assets. Some assets relate to an Organisation and some never will. For the ones that do relate to an Organisation, the other columns, Location and Language are applicable. If Organisation is NULL. Then Language and Location are redundant columns for those assets.

To me, this sounds like I have a table that is incorrectly storing the two types of assets. Internal and External assets. Internal are not constrained by Organisation, Language and Location, whilst External assets are.

However, I'm not entirely sure how to change the structure to reflect this. Regardless of whether they are Internal or External assets, they can still both have many AssetSettings associated with them. The external assets will have a different set of AssetSettings dependent upon there Organisation, Location_Id and Language_Id whereas an internal asset won't. They will only ever have one collection of settings each.

I'm not sure whether to:

1. Just leave the structure as it is because it works. Although it isn't normalised correctly.
2. Try and restructure the tables to allow for both types of assets and if so, how.

**Sample data**
Here is some sample data to hopefully make a bit more sense of what I'm asking:

**OrganisationAssets**

```
+----+----------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+
| Id | Asset_Id | Organisation_Id | Location_Id | Language_Id |
+----+----------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+
|  1 |        1 | 2               | 3           | 4           |
|  2 |        1 | 2               | 3           | 999         |
|  3 |        2 | NULL            | NULL        | NULL        |
+----+----------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+
```

The first two rows are for AssetId 1. It belongs to two different locations and is an **External** asset.
The third row is an **Internal** asset therefore the other columns are redundant.

**AssetSettings**

```
+----+------------------------+------+--------+
| Id | OrganisationalAsset_Id | Key  | Value  |
+----+------------------------+------+--------+
|  1 |                      1 | Key1 | Value1 |
|  2 |                      1 | Key1 | Value1 |
|  3 |                      2 | KeyA | ValueA |
|  4 |                      3 | KeyB | ValueB |
+----+------------------------+------+--------+
```

In the AssetSettings table. We can see two lots of settings for the Asset with Id1 (i.e. OrganisationalAsset_Id 1 and 2).
We can also see the second asset appearing in the table and it can only ever have one group of settings as it does not belong to any organisation, location or language.

Comment: One recommendation I would make is to stop using ID as the column name in any table. If it is an OrganizationID it should be that in every table. ID is too ambiguous imho and a column that changes names across tables is just plain awful to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as I can see from the structure you have described the best solution to normalize your data is to **move** all of those 3 fields (**Organisation_Id**, **Location_Id**, **Language_Id**) to [**AssetSettings**] table. In this case you would avoid having NULL values for inappropriate assets and you always can refer to required field wherever and whenever you need to.

And you can totally remove **OrganisationalAsset** table and link **AssetSettings** table straight to **Assets** table.

And you still have all the assets in **one** table, so you do not have to **split** them in **two** tables, in which the most common issue to arise is having **two** ID fields for assets, so you would need to keep additional **AssetType** field for every table that contains **AssetId**.

Comment: I can do this. However, am I just moving the problem to the AssetSettings table? For those assets that don't ever associate with an Organisation/Language/Location, it will always be NULL. However, for the External assets, the Organisation is always required. I've updated my question with some sample data.

Comment: Sorry, it's probably my fault not explaining it well. I didn't mean to move them AS IS, I meant that you should have [Key] = Organisation_Id and appropriate value for those assets, which have such information. I didn't mean to add new fields to the table.

Comment: So if your Asset#1 has Organisation_Id it would have appropriate row in AssetSettings table - Id = Identity, OrganisationalAsset_Id = 1, [Key] = Organisational_Id, Value = 149. If it has Language_Id value - another row, Id = Identity, OrganisationalAsset_Id = 1, [Key] = Language_Id, Value = 3

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dense but I'm not sure what you're saying. Can you edit your answer with the type of table structure you're thinking of?

Comment: Just imagine that your Organisation_Id, Location_Id and Language_Id are settings for an Asset. And you need them to store to AssetSettings table same way you do with other settings? And do not hesitate to ask for more details, I am glad to help you. If you can give an example of what data is stored to AssetSettings table, I'll try to update answer with exactly what I mean :)

Comment: I think I see what you're saying now. The language and location for example would become settings of an asset in the AssetSettings table. I can't do this as it means I can no longer have foreign keys that reference my Location, Language and Organisation tables. My fault for not stating they were other tables those columns referenced.

Comment: Well, in that case you might move them to separate tables then, well at least for languages, because as I understand one asset might have two languages assigned, so normal form clearly says that in that case it should be moved out to separate table. And it's OK if you have NULLs in Organisational_Assets table, if you don't want to mess with bunch of three_id_column tables (ID identity, Asset_Id int FK, Organisation_Id int FK) and so on. But it's still ok to have this data spread accross tables, so it's all up to you which way to go.

Answer (score 0):

1) This seems reasonable, it's a choice between redundancy and simplicity, understanding the data, usage etc. will help youu in this decision.

2) As you've identified two distinct kinds of `Assets` why not model it as such

```
Assets (Id, Name, AssetType_Id) 
    -- Id is PK

AssetTypes (Id, Name)
    -- Id is PK

InternalAssets (Id, AssetSettings_Id) 
    -- Id is PK and FK referencing Assets(Id)
    -- AssetSettings_Id is FK referencing AssetSettings

ExternalAssets (Id, Asset_Id, AssetSettings_Id, Organisation_Id, Location_Id, Language_Id)
    -- Id is PK 
    -- Asset_Id is FK referencing Assets(Id)
    -- AssetSettings_Id is FK referencing AssetSettings

AssetSettings (Id, Setting1, Setting2, Setting3)
    -- Id is PK
```

You may want to add a constraint such that an InternalAsset cannot be an ExternalAsset and vice versa.

You could also create a view of `OrganisationalAssets` which would union the two `*Assets` tables which may aid to simplify querying.

Comment: My only problem with this is the AssetSettings table. if I have a single Asset (in Assets table) and it belongs to the same Organisation and Location but has two different languages (In ExternalAssets as it's one-to-many). It means that I can have two sets of AssetSettings, one for each ExternalAsset. One for Location x and one for Location Y. When I try to get the AssetSettings for Location X, I can't as AssetSettings doesn't understand the concept of an ExternalAsset.

Comment: I think this issue can be resolved by not using an EAV table for the `AssetSettings`, see my updated answer.